# Average duplicates before fitting?

Tags: error, fitting, mean

Common practice for calibration curves is to take several duplicate measurements for each timepoint (or concentration, whatever variable) and fit using the average of each measurement set. The dependent and independent variables are both known.

E.g. a 3-point calibration with 5 duplicates generates 15 datapoints, but we only fit against the 3 average values.

What is the major difference with fitting against all 15 datapoints, other than being less computationally intensive? Is there even a difference?

Answer (score 4):

One big advantage to including all the data points rather than just analyzing the average value at each time point or concentration is that you get information on the variability of the measurements. In analytical systems this is a very important characteristic that one often wants to determine. Including all the data points also will provide more reliable estimates of the errors in the coefficients for the calibration curve, as the information about measurement error is pooled among all the data points rather than confounded into the average values at each concentration or time point.

It's almost never a good idea to throw away information. Now that we are no longer limited by the hand-operated calculators that were the norm half a century ago, the issue of computational intensiveness seldom matters except with immense data sets.

Comment: but it doesn't affect the coefficients from a linear least squares fit? that's normally all we care about when calibrating...

Comment: And by immense they mean greater than 10 TB uncompressed.  A decent data store, or even a really small one (SQLite3) can handle quite a bit of data, and if you know even rudimentary assembler then you can condense your data down to a few percent (~2% to 5%) of its full size with typically zero loss of information.  You can then run queries against it in SQL and do what has to be done.  And there are robust fits that give better generalizations of central tendency even in the presence of outliers.  When you are going to have any expectation of consistent output then you must control variation.

Comment: If you always have all three replicates (never one missing, for example) the coefficients will be the same, but besides being able to estimate the variability (and so get standard errors, confidence intervals, p-values etc) correctly you can also easily tell lack of fit from noise without needing to fit another model (or smooth the residuals) to get an estimate of the lack of fit vs "pure noise". Unless you *have* to average I'd strongly suggest not doing it.

Comment: You might also find keeping track of measurement variability to be useful for quality control.